# Why is my matrix row group sort not working in SSRS

Tags: sorting, matrix, reporting-services

I have a matrix where the rows are being pulled from a DB and they are showing as follows:

```
Critical
High
Informational
Low
Medium
```

I need them to show like this:

```
Critical
High
Medium
Low
Informational
```

Currently, I am going to the row group properties, and I am choosing sort, and entering in the following expression.

```
=IIF(Fields!Risk.Value = "Critical", 1, IIF(Fields!Risk.Value = "High", 2, IIF(Fields!Risk.Value = "Medium", 3, IIF(Fields!Risk.Value = "Low", 4, 5))))
```

When I generate a report, it now only has 1 row.  Just the "critical" row.  All other rows are missing.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

When I use this:

=iif(Fields!Risk.Value = "Critical", "1", iif(Fields!Risk.Value = "High", "2", iif(Fields!Risk.Value = "Medium", "3", iif(Fields!Risk.Value = "Low", "4", iif(Fields!Risk.Value = "Informational", "5", "")))))

all the rows show again but in the incorrect order as if no sort is being done at all.

Answer (score 1):

It may be cleaner and more precise to make the risk identifier available through the actual dataset rather than at runtime of the report. In your original dataset you could include a case statement within your select sql statement:

CASE [Risk]
  WHEN 'Critical' THEN '1' 
  WHEN 'High' THEN '2'
  WHEN 'Medium' THEN '3' 
  WHEN 'Low' THEN '4'
  ELSE '5' 
END as risk_identifier

You would then include "risk_identifier" in your tablix/matrix and would be available to group by or sort by.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

Try to generate an identifier for this data using Row_Number() function in your database. Then you can specify it un your row group.
Try a switch ssrs expression instead of a nested iif as follows:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "Low", "Green",
Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "Moderate", "Blue",
Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "Medium", "Yellow",
Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "High", "Orange",
Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "Very High", "Red"
)
```